# AWS RDS Postgres Crypto functions doesn't work even with the pgcrypto extension enabled

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgcrypto

I have the fresh AWS RDS Postgres (v 11) instance. I've installed the `pgcrypto` extension and it doesn't allow to do that again:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
Error in query (7): ERROR: extension "pgcrypto" already exists
```

But I can't use the extension functions:

```
select gen_salt('bf');
Error in query (7): ERROR: function gen_salt(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select gen_salt('bf')
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting....

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135093/in-rds-digest-function-is-undefined-after-creating-pgcrypto-extension

Comment: You could find it in the catalogs I guess. If you didn't install it yourself then you should add an answer here after you find the fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that the extension probably was added when a schema was active. Thank you @ Antti Haapala for the link to the same question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135093/in-rds-digest-function-is-undefined-after-creating-pgcrypto-extension .

I've made the following when no schema selected:

```
DROP EXTENSION pgcrypto;
Query executed OK, 0 rows affected. (0.031 s)

CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
Query executed OK, 0 rows affected. (0.046 s)

SELECT gen_salt('bf');
gen_salt
$2a$06$kyj11fcRtpwxrqgCfZEIaO
```

And everything works fine now.