# Supabase Self hosting issue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to host Supabase with a separate PostgreSQL DB. According to their docs, they say that Supabase uses `pgjwt` for auth. However, AWS RDS or Azure PosrgreSQL doesnt not support `pgjwt`.

[image]

Is there an alternate for pgjwt for PostgreSQL??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create the JWT functions manually as recommended [here](https://github.com/michelp/pgjwt/issues/4#issuecomment-310977339).

Just copy and run the SQL code from [postgres-jwt-prototype](https://github.com/larsar/postgres-jwt-prototype).

Create JWT Utils:

```
CREATE SCHEMA jwt;
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jwt.url_encode(data BYTEA)
  RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
SELECT translate(encode(data, 'base64'), E'+/=\n', '-_');
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jwt.url_decode(data TEXT)
  RETURNS BYTEA LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
WITH t AS (SELECT translate(data, '-_', '+/')),
    rem AS (SELECT length((SELECT *
                           FROM t)) % 4) -- compute padding size
SELECT decode(
    (SELECT *
     FROM t) ||
    CASE WHEN (SELECT *
               FROM rem) > 0
      THEN repeat('=', (4 - (SELECT *
                             FROM rem)))
    ELSE '' END,
    'base64');
$$;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jwt.algorithm_sign(signables TEXT, secret TEXT, algorithm TEXT)
  RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
WITH
    alg AS (
      SELECT CASE
             WHEN algorithm = 'HS256'
               THEN 'sha256'
             WHEN algorithm = 'HS384'
               THEN 'sha384'
             WHEN algorithm = 'HS512'
               THEN 'sha512'
             ELSE '' END) -- hmac throws error
SELECT jwt.url_encode(public.hmac(signables, secret, (SELECT *
                                               FROM alg)));
$$;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jwt.sign(payload JSON, secret TEXT, algorithm TEXT DEFAULT 'HS256')
  RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
WITH
    header AS (
      SELECT jwt.url_encode(convert_to('{"alg":"' || algorithm || '","typ":"JWT"}', 'utf8'))
  ),
    payload AS (
      SELECT jwt.url_encode(convert_to(payload :: TEXT, 'utf8'))
  ),
    signables AS (
      SELECT (SELECT *
              FROM header) || '.' || (SELECT *
                                      FROM payload)
  )
SELECT (SELECT *
        FROM signables)
       || '.' ||
       jwt.algorithm_sign((SELECT *
                           FROM signables), secret, algorithm);
$$;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jwt.verify(token TEXT, secret TEXT, algorithm TEXT DEFAULT 'HS256')
  RETURNS TABLE(header JSON, payload JSON, valid BOOLEAN) LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
SELECT
  convert_from(jwt.url_decode(r [1]), 'utf8') :: JSON                  AS header,
  convert_from(jwt.url_decode(r [2]), 'utf8') :: JSON                  AS payload,
  r [3] = jwt.algorithm_sign(r [1] || '.' || r [2], secret, algorithm) AS valid
FROM regexp_split_to_array(token, '\.') r;
$$;
```

Create sensitive:

```
CREATE SCHEMA sensitive;
CREATE TABLE sensitive.data (
  org_no TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  secret TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sensitive.token_secret (
  shared_secret TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sensitive.get_data(token TEXT, OUT secret TEXT)
  RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
DECLARE
  _shared_secret TEXT := (SELECT shared_secret
                          FROM sensitive.token_secret
                          LIMIT 1);

BEGIN
  WITH verifiedToken AS (SELECT *
                         FROM jwt.verify(token, _shared_secret)),
      verified_org_no AS ( SELECT payload ->> 'orgNo'
                           FROM verifiedToken
                           WHERE VALID IS TRUE )
  SELECT d.secret
  FROM sensitive.data d
  WHERE org_no = (SELECT *
                  FROM verified_org_no) AND org_no IS NOT NULL
  INTO secret;

END;
$$;
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the comment. I tried the first snippet.. It gave error for public.hmac not being a function. Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: Hey @Yash, that's a different problem. It sounds like you are missing pgcrypto.

Check these two posts: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311405/aws-rds-postgres-crypto-functions-doesnt-work-even-with-the-pgcrypto-extension)  & [DBA question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135093/in-rds-digest-function-is-undefined-after-creating-pgcrypto-extension)